# Write a Script to start JBoss server in install4j

Tags: java, jboss, exe, install4j

I have installed my application through Install4j and I am manually writing the following command

```
sh standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

on the terminal.so where and how can I write a script in install4j so that it can start server automatically ? Please give Steps to write the script ?

Answer (score 0):

install4j can generate service launchers. You define them in the launchers section. The "Install a service" action copies the generated script to /etc/init.d, then you can integrate it into the init sequence (as of 5.1 this is not done automatically sue to differences in various distributions).